# how to test the performance of compareAndSet between synchronized

Tags: java, jmh

I wnat to use CAS to improve my code ,but i doubt it can get better performance,so i do a test. here is the test code,this jmh code is reliable？

```
    @OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
    @BenchmarkMode(Mode.SampleTime)
    @Warmup(iterations = 5)
    @Measurement(iterations = 10, time = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    @Threads(20)
    @Fork(1)
    @State(Scope.Benchmark)
    public class CASBench {
        private int id=24;
        private static Object[] lockObj;
        private static AtomicReference<Integer>[] locks;
        static {
            lockObj = new Object[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < lockObj.length; i++) {
                lockObj[i] = new Object();
            }

            locks = new AtomicReference[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < locks.length; i++) {
                locks[i] = new AtomicReference<Integer>(null);
            }
        }
        @Benchmark
        public void sync() throws Exception {
            int index = id % 100;
            synchronized (lockObj[index]) {
                test();
            }
        }
        @Benchmark
        public void cas() throws Exception {
            AtomicReference<Integer> lock = locks[id % 100];
            while (!lock.compareAndSet(null, id)) {
            }
            test();
            lock.compareAndSet(id, null);
        }

        public void test() throws Exception {
            int sum=0;
            for(int i=0;i<100;i++){
                sum += i;
            }
        }
    }
```

and i get jmh test result:

```
Benchmark                     Mode       Cnt    Score    Error  Units
CASBench.cas                sample  25866638    0.014 ±  0.001  ms/op
CASBench.cas:cas·p0.00      sample             ≈ 10⁻⁶           ms/op
CASBench.cas:cas·p0.50      sample             ≈ 10⁻⁴           ms/op
CASBench.cas:cas·p0.90      sample              0.001           ms/op
CASBench.cas:cas·p0.95      sample              0.001           ms/op
CASBench.cas:cas·p0.99      sample              0.001           ms/op
CASBench.cas:cas·p0.999     sample              0.002           ms/op
CASBench.cas:cas·p0.9999    sample             38.164           ms/op
CASBench.cas:cas·p1.00      sample            813.695           ms/op
CASBench.sync               sample  26257757    0.011 ±  0.001  ms/op
CASBench.sync:sync·p0.00    sample             ≈ 10⁻⁶           ms/op
CASBench.sync:sync·p0.50    sample             ≈ 10⁻⁴           ms/op
CASBench.sync:sync·p0.90    sample              0.001           ms/op
CASBench.sync:sync·p0.95    sample              0.001           ms/op
CASBench.sync:sync·p0.99    sample              0.005           ms/op
CASBench.sync:sync·p0.999   sample              1.883           ms/op
CASBench.sync:sync·p0.9999  sample             15.270           ms/op
CASBench.sync:sync·p1.00    sample             45.810           ms/op
```

can I get this conclusion,in this case synchronized is better?

Answer (score 1):

Well your test are incorrect indeed **as far as I can tell**. First your benchmarks should return a value, as specified in the samples [here](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/7acb946af0e2/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_09_Blackholes.java) or use `BlackHoles`.

Than there are two ways to test this, first when there is `contention` and there isn't.

Let's see what happens under contention, it's simpler to grasp:

```
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
public class Contention {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {

        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .jvmArgs("-ea")
                .shouldFailOnError(true)
                .include(Contention.class.getSimpleName()).build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    private AtomicInteger atomic;

    private Object lock = new Object();

    private int i = 0;

    @Setup
    public void setUp() {
        atomic = new AtomicInteger(0);
    }

    @Fork(1)
    @Threads(10)
    @Benchmark
    public int incrementAtomic() {
        return atomic.incrementAndGet();
    }

    @Fork(1)
    @Threads(10)
    @Benchmark
    public int incrementSync() {
        synchronized (lock) {
            ++i;
        }

        return i;
    }
}
```

The code should be pretty much self-explanatory; with a slight explanation here :

```
 State(Scope.Benchmark)
```

If you change that to : `State(Scope.Thread)` *each* thread will get it's *own lock* and as such this code would be skewed by `biased-locking`. 
What that means that if you would run this code with :

```
 State(Scope.Thread)
```

Your output would be very much the same. Something like this:

```
Benchmark                                     Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
casVSsynchronized.Contention.incrementAtomic  avgt    5  36.526 ± 6.548  ns/op
casVSsynchronized.Contention.incrementSync    avgt    5  23.655 ± 3.393  ns/op
```

Running it with:

```
@State(Scope.Benchmark)
```

Shows an entire different picture. **Under contention CAS performs way better** as you can see from results:

```
Benchmark                                     Mode  Cnt    Score    Error  Units
casVSsynchronized.Contention.incrementAtomic  avgt    5  212.997 ± 42.902  ns/op
casVSsynchronized.Contention.incrementSync    avgt    5  457.896 ± 46.811  ns/op
```

Than I have a bit of a more complicated test (which might need more restrictive reviews from jmh devs probably):

```
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
public class CASSync {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RunnerException {

        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .jvmArgs("-ea")
                .shouldFailOnError(true)
                .include(CASSync.class.getSimpleName()).build();
        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    static public class AtomicHolder {

        AtomicInteger i = null;

        @Setup(Level.Invocation)
        public void setUp() {
            i = new AtomicInteger(0);
        }

        @TearDown(Level.Invocation)
        public void tearDown() {
            assert i.intValue() == 1;
            i = null;
        }

    }

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    static public class SyncHolder {

        int i = 0;

        Object lock = null;

        @Setup(Level.Invocation)
        public void setUp() {
            lock = new Object();
            i = 0;
        }

        @TearDown(Level.Invocation)
        public void tearDown() {
            assert i == 1;
            lock = null;
        }

    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(1)
    public boolean cas(AtomicHolder holder) {
        return holder.i.compareAndSet(0, 1);
    }

    @Benchmark
    @Fork(1)
    public boolean sync(SyncHolder holder) {
        synchronized (holder.lock) {
            ++holder.i;
        }

        return holder.i == 1;
    }

}
```

This one tests the case when there is no contention at all (just like the first one), but this time getting rid of `biased-locking`. And the results:

```
 Benchmark                       Mode  Cnt   Score   Error  Units
 casVSsynchronized.CASSync.cas   avgt    5  44.003 ± 1.343  ns/op
 casVSsynchronized.CASSync.sync  avgt    5  50.744 ± 1.370  ns/o
```

---

My conclusion: for contended environments, CAS is way better. For the rest it's debatable.

Comment: i add this function in your code `public int cas() throws Exception {
        int i;
        do {
            i = atomicInteger.get();
        } while (!atomicInteger.compareAndSet(i, i + 1));
        return i + 1;
    }` the function is the worst. use compareAndSet Explicit is not a good idea?

Comment: @twogoods I can't really understand what you added and where *exactly*. Have you declare a new variable called `atomicInteger`? Also why a while loop?

Comment: compareAndSet and while loop is one way to implement incrementAndGet，if you use AtomicReference<T> you must use compareAndSet in you code ,so use compareAndSet explicit will match better in some code scene.